# Powershell Remove spaces in the header only of a csv

Tags: powershell

First line of csv looks like this spaces are at after Path as well

```
author    ,Revision  ,Date      ,SVNFolder ,Rev,Status,Path
```

I am trying to remove spaces only and rest of the content will be the same .

```
author,Revision,Date,SVNFolder,Rev,Status,Path
```

I tried below

```
Import-CSV .\script.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.Trimend()}
```

Comment: `get-content` of the .csv and manipulate the first line then `convertto-csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The solutions below avoid loading the entire CSV file into memory.

First, get the header row and fix it by removing all whitespace from it:

```
$header = (Get-Content -TotalCount 1 .\script.csv) -replace '\s+'
```

If you want to *rewrite* the CSV file to fix its header problem:

```
# Write the corrected header and the remaining lines to the output file.
# Note: I'm outputting to a *new* file, to be safe.
#       If the file fits into memory as a whole, you can enclose
#       Get-Content ... | Select-Object ... in (...) and write back to the
#       input file, but note that there's a small risk of data loss, if 
#       writing back gets interrupted.
& { $header; Get-Content .\script.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 } |
  Set-content -Encoding utf8 .\fixed.csv
```

<sup>Note: I've chosen `-Encoding utf8` as the example output character encoding; adjust as needed; note that the default is ASCII(!), which can result in data loss.</sup>

If you just want to *import* the CSV using the fixed headers:

```
& { $header; Get-Content .\script.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 } | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Import-Csv` uses the column names in the header as property names of the custom objects it constructs from the input rows.

This property names are locked in at the time of reading the file, and cannot be changed later - unless you explicitly construct new custom objects from the old ones with the property names trimmed.

> `Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object {$_.Trimend()}`

Since `Import-Csv` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances, reflected one by one in `$_` in the `ForEach-Object` block, your code tries call `.TrimEnd()` directly on them, which will fail (because it is only `[string]` instances that have such a method).

Aside from that, as stated, your goal is to trim the *property names* of these objects, and that cannot be done without constructing new objects.

Answer (score 1):

expanding on the comment with an example since it looks like you may be new:

```
$text = get-content .\script.csv
$text[0] = $text[0] -replace " ", ""
$csv = $text | ConvertFrom-CSV
```

Comment: hmmm ... if only I could guess what "not working" means.  It works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file into an array:

```
$a = Get-Content test.txt
```

Replace the spaces in the first array element (`[0]`) with empty strings:

```
$a[0] = $a[0] -replace " ", ""
```

Write over the original file: (Don't forget backups!)

```
$a | Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: I don't think the intent is to update the source by overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inFilePath = "C:\temp\headerwithspaces.csv"
$content = Get-Content $inFilePath
$csvColumnNames = ($content | Select-Object -First 1) -Replace '\s',''
$csvColumnNames = $csvColumnNames -Replace '\s',''
$remainingFile = ($content | Select-Object -Skip 1)
```